# .htaccess 301 redirect all pages on old domain to a single page on new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm looking to redirect **each and every page** on the old domain to a **single page** on the new domain. It should also redirect both the www and non-www versions. Every single request to the domain old.com, whatever it may be, should lead to www.new.com root.

```
old.com/1.php
www.old.com/2.php
old.com/2.php
old.com/links/index.php
old.com/about-us.html
old.com/?string=1
```

should all redirect to:

www.new.com/

I'm looking for a .htaccess solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch in the old.com vhost

```
RedirectMatch permanent .* http://www.new.com/
```

`Redirect` appends the trailing portion of the matched URI to the redirection URI but with `RedirectMatch` it's up to you to choose the parts (if any) that you want to transfer using parentheses and `$number` references.

If the old and new domains must be aliases for the same document root on disk then you'll probably have to use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.new.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Works for most pages but not for www.old.com/?string=1

Comment: The second solution also doesn't redirect www.old.com/?string=1 (which is the equivalent of www.old.com/index.php?string=1). It does redirect all URLs which are in form of folders though (www.old.com/folder/)

Comment: @DanHorvat If you append a question mark `?` to the new domain, the query string will be removed `RewriteRule .* http://www.new.com/? [L,R=301]`

Comment: In order to keep all query strings, please add `[QSA]` at the end of the line containing the RewriteRule

Comment: This is the working solution. Redirect ALL pages to a single page on a new domain.

Answer (score 4):

This has already been answered, but here's the code altogether containing helpful comments so people have a reference to look back on later should they forget what it does.

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
## Each and every page on old domain redirects to single page
## By appending question mark to new domain, query strings are removed
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.new.com/? [L,R=301]
```

You can also redirect to a sub directory on another domain, as was the case that I needed to do like this:

```
## Each and every page on old domain redirects to single page
## By appending question mark to new domain, query strings are removed
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.new.com/sub-directory/? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle all your redirects including query strings. Excuse the formatting, I'm on a phone :)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$ RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new.com$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```