# 301 Redirect Domain and Subdomains with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I am moving a site to a new domain and need the whole structure (of subdomains and domains) to stay intact while using a 301 redirect.

> http://example.com/test/page
>   to
>   http://example2.com/test/page

also

> http://wildcard.example.com/test/page/random
>   to
>   http://wildcard.example2.com/test/page/random

Comment: I think you'll need an htaccess file for each subdomain. [You should look at this answer for the permanent redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15057194/1572077)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://example.com/test/page [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/test/page [L,R=301,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://wildcard.example.com/test/page/random [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wildcard.example2.com/test/page/random [L,R=301,NC]
```

you can use it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found was....

**For the main domain:**

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [L,R=301]

**For each subdomain:**

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^each-subdomain.example.com [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://each-subdomain.example2.com/$1 [L,R=301]